# Can I use JQuery to randomize the output quotes in this code?

Tags: jquery

I would like to adapt a non-random quote generator using JQuery and have the quotes output at random. I have tried two scripts below although I cannot get either to work. I would like the unordered list to be randomized every time the page is loaded. Please can anyone help me out with this?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function(){
var ul = document.querySelector('.word-container');
for (var i = ul.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    ul.appendChild(ul.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
}
</script>
```

or

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function(){
var ul = document.querySelector('.word-container'),
    temp = ul.cloneNode(true),
    i = temp.children.length + 1;
while( i-- > 0 )
temp.appendChild( temp.children[Math.random() * i |0] );
ul.parentNode.replaceChild(temp, ul);
</script>
```

and

```
      <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> -->
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Your Name">

    <title>jQuery Responsive Quote Rotator Demo</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/quoterotator.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.quoterotator.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#words').quoteRotator();
    });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="words">
        <ul class="word-container">
            <li data-author="---  Morrie Schwartz" data-easeout="lightSpeedOut" data-authorlink="http://codecanyon.net/user/sike">The most important thing in life is to learn how to give out love, and to let it come in. </li>
            <li data-link="http://codecanyon.net/user/sike" data-linkword="1" data-author="" data-easeout="fadeOutDown">Support link now. The animation can be in random or pre-defined in the HTML. Next quote animation will be all in fadeInDown. Optional click to next quote and hover to pause the slideshow.</li>
            <li data-author="" data-link="http://codecanyon.net/user/sike/portfolio" data-linkword="all">所 有 的 瞬 间 都 会 淹 没 于 时 间 的 洪 流，就 像 泪 水 消 逝 在 雨 中。 All those moments will be lost in time, like tears in rain.</li>
            <li data-author="Mark Twain (1835 - 1910)" data-easein="fadeInDown">Always do right. This will gratify some people and astonish the rest. </li>
            <li data-author="---  Susan Rice, Stanford University Commencement, 2010" data-easeout="bounceOut">Progress is the product of human agency. Things get better because we make them better. Things go wrong when we get too comfortable, when we fail to take risks or seize opportunities. </li>
            <li data-author="---  Arlo Guthrie (1947 - )" data-easein="bounceIn">You can't have a light without a dark to stick it in. </li>
            <li data-author="---  Mahatma Gandhi (1869 - 1948)" data-easein="lightSpeedIn">You must not lose faith in humanity. Humanity is an ocean; if a few drops of the ocean are dirty, the ocean does not become dirty. </li>
            <li data-author="---  Abraham Lincoln (1809 - 1865), (attributed)">When I do good, I feel good; when I do bad, I feel bad, and that is my religion. </li>
            <li data-author="---  John Wanamaker (1838 - 1922), (attributed)">Half the money I spend on advertising is wasted; the trouble is I don't know which half. </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="quote">
            <blockquote>
              <p class="quote-content"></p>
            </blockquote>
            <cite class="quote-author"></cite>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#words').quoteRotator();

    var $container = $('.word-container'),
        $quotes = $.makeArray($container.children());

    $quotes.sort(function(){ return (Math.random() > .5 ? -1 : 1)  });

    $.each($quotes,function(i,el){
        $container.prepend(el);
    });
});
</script>
```

Depending on how your quote rotator plugin works, you might have to move `$('#words').quoteRotator();` to the end of the function.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer although I fear I am inserting it incorrectly into the code. I have modified the question with your code, although it doesn't work. Please can you help me to correct the syntax? I apologize, I am very new to this.

Comment: @Terry Editing an answer into the code is not good practice. Please remove it, as others may think that I pasted the code from the question. I've updated the answer, I believe the issue was that I wrote `$('.word.container')` instead of `$('.word-container')`.

Comment: DJDavid98 that worked perfectly. I cannot express my gratitude enough. I restored the question back to its original form and for other's reference, I did need to put $('#words').quoteRotator(); at the end of the function. Thanks again.

Comment: @Terry I'm glad I could help. Marking this as the accepted answer using the check mark below the votes will be a good expression of your gratitude :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! You can call `.empty()` on the `ul`, and then pass back the `li`s in shuffled form. You can see an example of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnFish/cfgqhonk/1/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply John. Your answer worked too, although it was easier for me to add DJDavid98's code as I am not at all experienced with coding.